# Using $(\neg \psi \to \neg \phi )\to (\phi \to \psi )$ as axiom3 of $L$, show $\vdash (((\psi \to \phi )\rightarrow \psi )\rightarrow \psi )$？

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to show $\vdash (((\psi \to \phi )\rightarrow \psi )\rightarrow \psi )$？Equivalently,$((\psi \to \phi )\rightarrow \psi )\vdash \psi $?Of course, by formal language $L$. The Axiom3 of $L$ is $(\neg \psi \to \neg \phi )\to (\phi \to \psi )$--not same to the answer already put on website.
This question came from *Logic for mathematicians* written by A. G. Hammilton, in the chapter 2 exercise3.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No big change needed*...

In A.G. Hammilton, [Logic for mathematicians](https://books.google.it/books?id=TO098EjWT38C&pg=PA35)'s proof system we have:

*Example 2.7* (page 31): $\vdash (\phi\to \phi)$.

*Prop.2.8* (Deduction Theorem, page 32).

*Prop.2.11* (page 35): (a) $\vdash (\lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi))$
and (b) $\vdash ((\lnot \phi\to \phi) \to \phi)$.

Now for the main proof :

1. $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ$ --- premise
2. $\lnot \phi$ --- premise
3. $\vdash \lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ --- *Prop.2.11 (a)*
4. $\phi \to \psi$ --- from 2) and 3) by *MP*
5. $\phi$ --- from 1) and 4) by *mp*
6. $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ \vdash \lnot \phi \to \phi$ --- from 2) and 5) by *Deduction Th*
7. $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ \vdash ϕ$ --- *Prop.2.11 (b)* and *MP*

> > $\vdash ((ϕ → ψ ) → ϕ) → ϕ$ --- from t) by *Deduction Th*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @yinfeng - If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it.